# What is the maximum number of partitions I can create in WindowsXp?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, partitioning

I know that I can create up to 24 partitions (C to Z), can we create more? and how?

Thanks.

Comment: There may be a distinction here: how many partitions can you create/how many partitions can you subsequently assign a drive letters to?

Comment: That's not corrent, @MatthewWilliams. If all drive letters (A-Z) are used up, new partitions will simply not be accessible unless you manually specify a mount point (in a folder).

Comment: @DanielB | I stand corrected then. Thanks for the information.

Comment: This does not seem like a real question.

Answer (score 0):

There is a distinction between partitions and mounted partitions. You could create as many partitions as you want, but as you mentioned, you can only mount them on drive letters C through Z.

Fortunately, Microsoft engineers built a way to get around this limitation. You can mount partitions as subfolders of 'drives'. So you could mount a partition on c:\myPartition.

This can be done from Disk Management. If you right-click an unmounted partition and select 'Change drive letters and paths' you can add a new mount point for the partition by using the 'Mount in the following empty NTFS folder' option.